# Cannot edit a question. URL results in "Page Not Found"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

For some reason, there is no `edit` or `retag` link underneath this question: [How to debug a local network from a PC that is infecting it](https://superuser.com/questions/371342/how-to-debug-a-local-network-from-a-pc-that-is-infecting-it)

[image: screenshot]

Similarly, when trying to access the edit function directly via URL ([`https://superuser.com/posts/371342/edit`](https://superuser.com/posts/371342/edit)) the page is "not found".

I tested this with other browsers (cleared caches/cookies, as well) with the same results. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: Strange, I suspect someone else was just editing the same question, because I just approved another one. Though that's just a guess on my part

Comment: **And now it's back!**...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design. There was a [pending suggested edit](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/7508) on the question and hence the edit/retag options were not available till the suggested edit was approved